# How to dynamically enable/disable Responsive extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, datatables

I have a project where users need to be able to select whether or not the accompanying script activates Responsive extension of jQuery DataTables.

I want to add a dropdown menu in HTML that lets users choose whether option `responsive` is set to `true` or `false` in `dataTable()` initialization options.

I tried to add a separate function to select the value and used a global variable to get it to the `dataTable()` function but couldn't get that to work.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#example").dataTable({

    "responsive": false,
    "processing": false,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "scripts/university.php",
    "columns": [
       // ID
       null, ........
```

*HTML**

```
  <select id="selected2" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="true">true</option>
  <option value="false">false</option>
  </select>
```

I tried adding a `document.getElementById` clause as the first line in the dataTable function but couldn't make it work.

What can I add to the existing function to make `responsive` option user selectable from the list on the HTML page?

Comment: I can not figure out what you really want to achieve? and where is the problem ?

Comment: I want users to be able to choose if responsive is set to true or false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

You need to destroy table to re-initialize it and enable/disable [Responsive](http://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) extension.

```
var dtOptions = {
    responsive: true           
};

var table = $('#example').DataTable(dtOptions);

$('#ctrl-select').on('change', function(){
    dtOptions.responsive = ($(this).val() === "1") ? true : false;

    $('#example').DataTable().destroy();
    $('#example').removeClass('dtr-inline collapsed');

    table = $('#example').DataTable(dtOptions);
});
```

**NOTES**

When the table is destroyed, Responsive extension leaves some classes (`dtr-inline`,  `collapsed`), so I remove them manually before initializing the table again.

Also I suggest having all options in a separate object `dtOptions` to make re-initialization easier, that way you just need to toggle one option `responsive`.

**DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/femjs7w1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out again Michael. I see how this is the right answer for my site, but having trouble implementing it. To clarify, I need to put my additional datatable options into the array right? Also, does it matter for the syntax if there is/isn't " marks around the values in the dtOption array?

Comment: @Ryanf, you don't need to put the options into a separate object `dtOption`, but it makes the code easier to maintain since you have set of options in one place. Quotes are not needed unless you use reserved words, it's a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is [this](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/init) DataTable plug-in then you can change the responsive setting in your myFunction. First,

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable(/* your current settings */);
```

then, in myFunction,

```
new $.fn.dataTable.Responsive( table, {
    details: true
} );
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not achieve a solution, I still don't know how to let users choose if new $.fn.dataTable.Responsive( table, {details: is set to true or false.

Answer (score 0):

honestly the solution is good for a simple datable without certain aditional option, but when you need to use filter or adding columns became a problem, best solution i found is the following...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var table = initializeDataTable(true); // Inicializar la tabla con responsive habilitado

$('#toggle-responsive').on('click', function() {
    var responsiveEnabled = !table.settings()[0].oInit.responsive; // Cambiar entre true y false
    table.destroy(); // Destruir la tabla actual
    table = initializeDataTable(responsiveEnabled); // Reconstruir la tabla con la nueva configuración
});
```

});

```
 function initializeDataTable(responsiveEnabled) {
var table = $('#id-table').DataTable({
    "responsive": responsiveEnabled,
```

});

```
return table;
```

}

then, html code

```
<button id="toggle-responsive">Change view</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using an onChange event handler to get the value whenever there is a change in the dropdown selection? I would think using the onChange to toggle a variable value and assigning it to whichever dataTable key would work. Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var selected;
 $('#selected2').onChange( function() {
     selected = $(this).val();
 }
 $("#example").dataTable({
    "responsive": false,
    "processing": selected,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "scripts/university.php",
    "columns": [
       // ID
       null, ........
```

Comment: `$(this).val()` will be the strings `"true"` or `"false"`. You need to convert `selected` to a boolean before using it in the `dataTable` call.

Comment: Tried this method, and tried it with boolean, couldn't get it.

Answer (score -1):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wbyqsnmL/2/)

Well get rid of the obtrusive javascript or use it `( onchange="myFunction()")`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selectedValue;
    $('#selected2').change( function() {
        selectedValue = $(this).val();
        alert(selectedValue);
    });
});
```

Comment: In your fiddle,`"processing": selected` calls an unknown variable, I changed it to `"processing": selectedValue` but that didn't work either. Any ideas?