# DataTables scrollable table instead of collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

Is it possible in [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) in mobile view set the table to horizontal scroll instead of "responsive" table which collapse the table?

actually my datatables looks like this in mobile:

[image]

and in expanded state it is so ugly as i have some buttons in last column so i would know if there is a way to make the table "full width" and just to see the other columns the user will have to scroll horizontally in that card..

Here is my datatable config

```
 $('#table').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        destroy: true,
        data: dati,
        select: false,
        ordering: false,
        lengthChange: false,
        pageLength: 5,
        info: false,
        pagingType: "numbers",
        dom: 'B<t><p>',
        columns: [
            {
                data: 'DATA',
                render: data => {
                    return moment(data).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
                }
            },
            { data: 'ORA' },
            { data: 'OPERATORE' },
            { data: 'OPERAZIONE' },
            {
                data: 'IMPORTO',
                render: data => {
                    return '€' + data.toFixed(2)
                }
            },
            {
                data: null,
                defaultContent: ''
            }
        ],
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'copy',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'csv',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'excel',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdf',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'print',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
                }
            }
        ],
        initComplete: function () {
            var $buttons = $('.dt-buttons').hide();
            $("#export_type").on("click", "a", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var btnClass = $(this).attr("data-export")
                    ? '.buttons-' + $(this).attr("data-export")
                    : null;
                if (btnClass) $buttons.find(btnClass).click();
            });
        }
    });
```

Actually i've yet tryed to set responsive to false and by setting scrollX to true, in mobile it's look "okay" but in web without responsive tag set to true it doesn't take full width and when the screen is resized it "breaks"

[image]

Comment: Somehow this is what you were looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486247/how-to-dynamically-enable-disable-responsive-extension

Comment: And also did you try setting `responsive: false`

Comment: @Awais check my updated question

Comment: Okay! Now i think you were talking about `breakpoints` right? like this [responsive.breakpoints](https://datatables.net/reference/option/responsive.breakpoints)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an object as the "responsive" setting to evaluate what the screen size is, so that you can set "responsive" to be false if the screen size is below a certain width.

For example:

```
const isLargerThanMobileScreen = ($(window).width() > 480) ? true : false;

$('#table').DataTable( {
   "scrollX": true,
   "responsive": isLargerThanMobileScreen, 
} );
```

Comment: Okaay actually i've also added: `const isMobile = ($(window).width() < 480) ? true : false;` and set it to scrollX as set only to true will show a table not in full width